# Understanding the optimistic locking StaleObjectStateException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been struggling with the `StaleObjectStateException` for more than a week now and decided to post here a simple app that reproduces the problem.

I understand the `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` is an **optimistic locking exception**. Furthermore, **optimistic locking relies on the use of a version field** in each of the entity classes.

Now let me explain how I reproduced the above exception: the sample app has an `Member` entity class which is as follows:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
public class Member {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
    //id, version fields as well as mutator/accessors are located in a separate Roo ITD/aspect  
}
```

Here is the `Address` entity class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
public class Address {

    private String formattedAddress;
    private double lng;
    private double lat;
    //id, version fields as well as mutator/accessors are located in a separate Roo ITD/aspect 
}
```

Using a **fresh/unmanaged Address instance** and a **managed Member instance**, I am trying to update the member's address in a `ServiceImpl` class as follows:

```
@Override
public void updateMemberAddress(Member member, Address address) {
    long addressId = member.getAddress().getId();
    address.setId(addressId);
    updateAddress(address);
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class AddressIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Before
    @Transactional
    public void testInsertOneMember() {
        Member member = new Member();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setFormattedAddress("Eiffel Tower, Paris");
        address.setLat(48.005);
        address.setLng(3.288);
        member.setAddress(address);
        service.saveMember(member);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testUpdateAddress() {
        Member member = service.findAllMembers().get(0);
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setFormattedAddress("Empire State Building, New York");
        address.setLat(200.033);
        address.setLng(36.665);
        service.updateMemberAddress(member, address);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the dreaded StaleObjectStateException as follows:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [org.sose.domain.Address#1];
```

Anyone wishing to reproduce the problem using the sample github app needs:

- Maven
- Git
- JDK 6
- MySQL

They can reproduce the problem by following the steps below:

- `git clone git@github.com:balteo/StaleObjectStateException.git`
- In mysql create a database schema called sose `create database sose;`
- `mvn test`
- and voila: `BOOM`!

Can anyone please explain to me why this exception is occurring in my case and how to update the address instance without getting this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1) When setting the address of a member, you should not modify the id but set the address object. `updateMemberAddress`should be like this

```
@Override
public void updateMemberAddress(Member member, Address address) {
  member.setAddress(address);
  updateMember(member);
}
```

2) You have a one-to-one relation between member and address. I don't know your exact data model, but as far as I can see member has an id and address does not have an explicitly defined id. This is not necessary, because address has the id of member which at the same moment it the primary key (1:1 relation).

But when you change the id of address (statement `address.setId(addressId);`) then you have at that moment two address objects (the old address which formerly was attached to the member and the new address) with the same primary key. Hibernate can't handle two instances with the same primary key.

You have to delete the old address instance before you attach the new one to this member. (A better solution would be to add a version number or a separate id to address and change the relation member:address to 1:n.)

Probably problem 2) produces the error.

Comment: Hi Johanna! Ummm... Address also has an id field defined. It is actually located in a separate aspectj file (as with Member for that matter). What happens if I don't set the id of address, is that I end up with another instance of Address in the address table...

Comment: And if you set the address id then you have only one instance in the database because the second instance is not written due to an exception ;-) . Even with a separate address id in address setting the id in the way you're doing this is nonsense. Then you also have two instances with the same primary key. In your statement `Address address = new Address();`you explicitly create a second address instance and this needs a unique id. If you do not want a second address instance you have to do this: `Address address = member.getAddress(); address.setXXX(...); service.updateMember(member);`

Comment: Using this: `Address address = member.getAddress();` I then have to manage/copy fields one by one which can be tedious if there are many fields. I wanted to avoid that actually.

Comment: In Hibernate one instance of a Java object is one database row. If you want to update the database row then you have to modify this Java instance. If you want to insert a new row then you have to create a new instance in Java. If you load the same row twice, both times you get back the same instance. You can't go around this behaviour. (All this is the case as long as you are using one Session instances. With more Session instances it is getting more complicated, but you can't avoid these restrictions.)